# java.net.UnknownHostException with Android app

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

i am having this challenge that have been driving me crazy and don't know how to fix it. I have developed an android application that will post some data to a remote url using post. here is my method to handle that

```
public static String fetchStringFromRemotePOST(String url,List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs){
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    Log.i("URL",url);
    String line = "";
    String content = "";
    try{
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          content += line;              
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("String Fetch ERROR",e.toString());
    }
    return content;
}
```

and to call the method

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post","okpokor"));      
String url = "http://wwww.host.com/post.php";    
String response = UtilMethod.fetchStringFromRemotePOST(url,nameValuePairs);
```

And also, i have included the internet permission in the Android manifest file

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
 ...
```

I have gone through the same problem discussed on other threads previously and none of the suggestions really worked for me, suggestions like re-starting the Eclipse and AVD.

Really need help!

Comment: you shouldn't concatenate Strings with +=, better use a StringBuilder instead

Comment: Your code looks okay. Have you tried using the Browser in your Emulator to check if the Emulator has Internet connection?

Comment: does your device actually have an internet connection ?

Comment: i have set the Internet permission in the manifest file Thommy but still did not work

Comment: please check do you really have internet connection by browsing internet

Comment: Voting to close as too localised due to spelling error in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your URL you have 4

> wwww

,
change it to :

> http://www.host.com/post.php

Comment: Thanks man, solved the problem that was a silly one from me...